# React forms when changing one input causes cascading changes to other inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-select

What is a good way in React to deal with web forms with interdependent state, where changes in one input element cause cascading, dynamic changes in other elements?

Here's one example: I'm building a React form with four [`react-select`](https://react-select.com/) components (let's call them A/B/C/D) and I'm trying to wire them up so that changes in one `Select` will cause changes in one or more of the others.

For example:

- If the user changes `A`, then reload the data in `B`. Try to maintain a similar selected option in `B` after the data is loaded. "Similar" means that if the new data contains an option with the same name, even if the underlying object is different, then keep that named option selected in `B`. Otherwise clear `B`'s selection.
- If the user changes `B`, then load `C` with a filtered subset of `A`'s data, with the selected option of `B` controlling how the filtering works. Like above, if the new contents of `C` have a same-named option (even if the underlying data is different) then keep it selected. Otherwise, clear the selection in `C`.
- If the user changes `A` and there's a selection in `B`, and if nothing is currently selected in `C`, then make the selection of `C` match the selected option of `A`.
- If the user changes `C` (including if it's changed via changes cascading from `A` or B!) then refresh the contents of `D`, but like above try to keep the same-named label selected in `D`, even if the data underneath it has changed.  Otherwise select the first option in the newly-populated `D`.

I'm fairly comfortable building React apps with controlled components where the state machine is simple and dependencies are clear. But in this case, the dependency tree is complicated!

I've already pushed my state (contents of `A`-`D` and their selected options) up to a container component.

But I'm finding that doing this is like pulling a thread on a sweater. After I moved the state up to the top, now I need domain-specific logic to determine what to do with the state, and that logic (e.g. getting data & translating it into user-visible UI in each component) is currently encapsulated in lower-level components. For example, component `A` is responsible for loading `A`'s data, `B` loads `B`'s data, etc.

Do I also need to move that logic up to the top-level component? Or is there some other pattern that I should consider for this kind of complex, interdependent UI state?

If it matters, I'm using plain React without any context, state-management or forms libraries, etc. Just `useState` and `react-select`.

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic reflexion, but it already seems difficult to explain how the form is supposed to work. Do you think a user will know?

Comment: @johannchopin Good question. My example is somewhat of a worst case, but I run into this kind of problem a lot, where one field affects what happens in other fields in a complex way. For example, a form where you're filling in a postal code which might auto-fill the city and (in USA) the state, but if you fill in city and state then it might give you a suggestion for the postal code. What the UI does depends on what thing the user did first or last. The general pattern shows up quite a bit, and I'm looking for general advice about how to deal with this scenario in React.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved by holding a component with the main state and logic for your `react-select` components. These `react-select` should be siblings of the same parent:

```
MyStateHolderComponent
   |
   | Holds state
   | const [someState, setSomeState] =useState(null)
   |
   +-- component A (on select, updates sameState from parent, you can drill a function to component A to do so)
   +-- component B (receives someState as prop. Every time component A updates, it will be re rendered with the new prop)
   +-- component C
   +-- component D
```

At the same time, component A, B, C, D might have a state on their own.
You can handle this architecture by drilling down callbacks that update the parent state, or is use the Context Api.